# combine video and audio .webm files based on wallclock times

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I have a node server recording webrtc streams as separate video/audio files via ffmpeg.
I'm running ffmpeg via node's

```
child_process.spawn('ffmpeg', commandArgs);
```

Unfortunately, when I try to combine video and audio files later on, I don't know when ffmpeg created the first frame of each file, resulting in out of sync faces and voices :(

Here's my command line args for piping the stream into ffmpeg

```
 '-loglevel',
  'debug',
  '-reorder_queue_size',
  '0',
  '-protocol_whitelist',
  'pipe,udp,rtp',
  '-fflags',
  '+genpts',
  '-f',
  'sdp',
  '-i',
  'pipe:0',
  '-map',
  '0:v:0',
  '-c:v',
  'copy',
  '-use_wallclock_as_timestamps',
  '1',
  '-timestamps',
  'mono2abs',
  '-flags',
  '+global_header',
  './recordings/video_1627600996166.webm'
```

I was thinking that it might be possible to set the timestamps of packets to the linux's clock times, and tried a bunch of flags (-timestamps abs, -timestamps mono2abs, -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1) but nothing seemed to change the result in the file. (I also have tried moving the time commands all around).

```
packet|codec_type=video|stream_index=0|pts=0|pts_time=0.000000|dts=0|dts_time=0.000000|duration=N/A|duration_time=N/A|convergence_duration=N/A|convergence_duration_time=N/A|size=14568|pos=552|flags=K_
```

Time always starts at 0.

Any help figuring out how to get accurate times from my recorded audio/video .webm files so I can accurately combine them would be amazing.

Thanks so much :)

Comment: Remove `-fflags +genpts`. Shift `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1` to before `-i`.

Comment: Hey, thanks Gyan, I gave that a try (-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i pipe:0 [and removed the other flags]) but still have |pts_time=0.000000|dts_time=0.000000 on the first frame.